# How do i select an item from readlines lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, readlines

So this is what i have so far for a class project

```
import os 

UserSelection = input("Select a txt file: ")

with open(UserSelection, 'r', encoding= "latin-1") as f:
    lines= f.readlines()


    print("These are your headers:", lines[0])

state = words()[6]

for i in range(1,len(lines)):
    words=line.split
       if(words()[6] == 'California'):
        print(lines)
```

i have a large census table and i'm trying to keep only lines where STATE(which is 6th index) is CA.
i thought
`words()[6]` would do it but its not.
thanks ahead!

Comment: Should be `words=lines[i].split()` which split on spaces and provides a list of words.  You may actually want to use `words=lines[i].rstrip().split()` which removes the carriage return at the end of each line.  Index 6 is then `words[6]`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. In the code that you post there are few lines that not so clear to understand.
1) `print("These are your headers:", lines[0])` is not indented properly.
2) `state = words()[6]` the words is not defined before this line. 
3) `for i in range(1,len(lines)):` in this line you are iterating over lines indexes without the first line can be replaces with `line in lines[1>]:`. 
4) `words=line.split` split method in lists is callable in python so you should use () when you use the method.
5)`if(words()[6] == 'California'):` unlike split words is a variable not a method so it should not be called with ().
The way as I understand for you code that the code should be is more like

```
import os 

userSelection = input("Select a txt file: ")

with open(userSelection ,'r', encoding= "latin-1") as f:
    lines= f.readlines()

print("These are your headers:", lines[0])

for line in lines[1:]:
    words=line.split()
    if words[6] == 'California':
        print(lines)
```

Answer (score -1):

It does work. Your error is indentation. Also, you have some other small errors.

```
. . .

for i in range(1,len(lines)):
  words=line.split()
  if (words[6] == 'California'):
    print(lines)
```

`.split()` is a function and should be called as one.

No need to unnecessarily indent either.
Replacing the code snippet above with your old `for` loop will do the trick.